# R - setting a value based on a function applied to other values in the same row

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe containing (surprise) data. I have one column which I wish to populated on a per-row basis, calculated from the values of other columns in the same row.

From googling, it seems like I need 'apply', or one of it's close relatives. Unfortunately I haven't managed to make it actually work.

Example code:

```
#Example function
getCode <- function (ar1, ar2, ar3){
  if(ar1==1 && ar2==1 && ar3==1){
    return(1)
  } else if(ar1==0 && ar2==0 && ar3==0){
    return(0)
  } 
  return(2)
}

#Create data frame
a = c(1,1,0)
b = c(1,0,0)
c = c(1,1,0)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
#Add column for new data
df[,"x"] <- 0

#Apply function to new column
df[,"x"] <- apply(df[,"x"], 1, getCode(df[,"a"], df[,"b"], df[,"c"]))
```

I would like df to be taken from:

```
  a b c x
1 1 1 1 0
2 1 0 1 0
3 0 0 0 0
```

to

```
  a b c x
1 1 1 1 1
2 1 0 1 2
3 0 0 0 0
```

Unfortunately running this spits out:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) :    'getCode(df[, "a"], df[, "b"], df[,
>   "c"])' is not a function, character or symbol

I'm new to R, so apologies if the answer is blindingly simple. Thanks.

Comment: The data frame you create is not the one you show. You show the first column as 1,1,0, but before you specify `a = c(1,1,1)`.

Comment: Slight copy and paste error. Now corrected. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things: apply would be along the dataframe itself (i.e. `apply(df, 1, someFunc)`); it's more idiomatic to access columns by name using the `$` operator.. so if I have a dataframe named `df` with a column named `a`, access a with `df$a`.

In this case, I like to do an `sapply` along the index of the dataframe, and then use that index to get the appropriate elements from the dataframe.

```
df$x <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) getCode(df$a[i], df$b[i], df$c[i]))
```

Answer (score 2):

As @devmacrile mentioned above, I would just modify the function to be able to get a vector with 3 elements as input and use it within an `apply` command as you mentioned.

```
#Example function
getCode <- function (x){
  ifelse(x[1]==1 & x[2]==1 & x[3]==1,
         1,
         ifelse(x[1]==0 & x[2]==0 & x[3]==0,
                0,
                2))    }


#Create data frame
a = c(1,1,0)
b = c(1,0,0)
c = c(1,1,0)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
df

#   a b c
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 1 0 1
# 3 0 0 0


# create your new column of results
df$x = apply(df, 1, getCode)
df

#   a b c x
# 1 1 1 1 1
# 2 1 0 1 2
# 3 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks - the problem with this method is that my actual "getCode" function operates across about eight different columns which would make chained ifelses a little unweildy! devmacrile's solution with sapply avoids this problem.

Comment: You're welcome. You should definitely use the one that's easier to apply to your process. Maybe using the column names instead of column positions is better as you don't have to change your function at all. However, column names and positions have a 1-to-1 relationship and you can definitely substitute names with positions in your function, without using any `ifelse`, but only `if`.

Comment: Having thought about it a bit more your answer began to make a lot more sense, and have just used it (containing ifs) to solve a different problem. Many ways to skin a cat, and yours was also a good one. Thanks again.